# Transposing vacuously true propositions: if $x^2 < 0$, then $x = 0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

According to [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), the proposition $(1)$ is true.

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x^2<0\implies x=0)\tag{1}$$

Now, if I transform the proposition $(1)$ using [transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(logic)), I arrive at $(2)$. Here I encounter an issue, as without transforming back, $(2)$ is not as easy to prove as $(1)$.

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x\neq0\implies x^2\geq0)\tag{2}$$

How do I prove proposition $(2)$ in the case where $x\neq 0$? How do I interpret the meaning of this new proposition $(2)$?

Comment: @tomasliam No, I mean x² < 0 indeed, it's pre-condition in original proposition  and x∈R

Comment: @tomasliam that is the idea. They are asking about the principal of explosion and vacuous truth. By assuming something that is false, you can derive anything. Their question (after demonstrating they already know about vacuous truth) is how to work with these type statements after applying the principal of transposition.

Comment: @tomasliam  According to [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), due to you couldn't find a real value that can satisfy 2<0, hence the set is empty, so the proposition is true, because the pre-condition is false, whether the conclusion is true or false, the proposition would always be true.

Comment: @tomasliam please wait for the OP to finish editing their question before closing it. It is a very good question once you understand what is being asked. The original proposition $\forall x\in R(x^2<0 \implies x=23)$ is not false, and is in fact a tautology, by virtue of the principal of explosion.

Comment: @user400188 I deleted my comment 3 mins before your last comment, clearly I realised my error.

Comment: The page didn't refresh in time for me. I didn't notice the comments been deleted, my apologies @tomasliam.

Comment: Not clear... the square of a non-zero real number is positive, because we can prove in arithmetic that negative times negative is positive.

Comment: Note that $x^2>0\implies x^2\geq 0$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes, however, the square of a non-zero always can't be zero, so I think the conclusion wouldn't be true.

Comment: $\ge$ means: "greater or equal" and we have that $P$ implies $P \text { or } Q$. In fact, $0 \ge 0$ holds.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, I see it. So it's also a true proposition?

Comment: Yes, because it is equiv to the original proposition.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But, I have to say, set y = x² ,if x ≠ 0, then what the range of y? you couldn't say it's [0,∞], you only can say it's (0,∞], due to x wouldn't be 0, I don't know why here, `if x ≠ 0, then x² ≥ 0`  is true, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I cannot understand you concern... We agree that "If $x^2 < 0$, then $x=0$" is true. Thus, by contraposition, also "If **not** $x=0$, then **not** $x^2<0$" is true.

Comment: @jackX, as Mauro says, $\ge$ means: "greater or equal". Then, $x \neq 0 \to (x^2 > 0 \lor x^2 = 0)$. For example, $2 \neq 0 \to (2^2 > 0 \lor 2^2 = 0)$. As $4 > 0$ is true, $4 > 0 \lor 4 = 0$ is also true.

Comment: @jackX You can say that its range is $[0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$, together this intersection is equivalent to saying that its range is $(0,\infty)$. A similar thing has happened here, we claim that when $x\neq 0$, and $x\neq 0\implies x^2\geq 0$ are true, that $x^2\geq 0~\land x\neq 0$ is true, which is equivalent to saying that $x^2>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Although the comments pretty much answer your question, I'll try to be slightly more pedantic in this answer. Before that, note that $(2)$ is indeed true since $(1)$ is and  taking contrapositives doesn't change the truth value of a statement (this is easy to see by  contructing a truth table, for example).

You are asking to prove that the statement $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x\neq0\implies x^2\geq0)\tag{2}$$ is true. I present here two proofs, one direct and the other not so much. The important point to note (and where I think the source of confusion resides) is that showing that $(2)$ is true is equivalent to showing that one of the following statements is true:

- $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x\neq0\implies x^2>0)$.
- $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x\neq0\implies x^2=0)$.

Why is this the case? This is due to our interpretation of the symbol $\geq$ in $\mathbb R$; if $x, y \in \mathbb R$, $x \geq y$ means that either $x > y$ **or** $x = y$; therefore, if you assume that $x \neq 0$ and you prove that $x^2 >0$, then $(2)$ follows.

---

**Proof 1:** Let $x \in \mathbb R$ and suppose that $x \neq 0$. We have to show that $x^2 \geq 0$, i.e. we have to show that either $x^2>0$ or $x^2=0$; if any of these hold, the truth of statement $(2)$ follows. Since $x \neq 0$ we have two cases:

1. $x>0$. Then $x^2>0$ since $x$ is a positive real number.
2. $x<0$. Then there exists $z>0$ such that $x = -z$. Then $x^2 = (-z)^2 = (-1)^2z^2 = z^2>0$, where the last inequality follows since $z$ is a positive real number.

In either case $x^2>0$, so if $x$ is a real number distinct from zero, $x^2 >0$. Therefore statement $(2)$ is true.

---

**Proof 2:** Assume for contradiction that $(2)$ is not true, i.e. assume that the statement $$\neg\left(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}~(x\neq0\implies x^2\geq0)\right)\tag{$\dagger$}$$ is true. Using the fact that $p \to q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$ and "moving the negation inside the expression", we have that $(\dagger)$ is logically equivalent to $$\exists x \in \mathbb R (x \neq 0 \wedge x^2<0) \tag{$\dagger\dagger$}.$$ However, note that $(\dagger\dagger)$ directly contradicts statement $(1)$ in your question, since any $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2 < 0$ must be $0$. Therefore our assumption was false and hence $(2)$ is true.